# How to Copy a blob in azure to another container with node sdk

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-node-sdk

I am trying to copy a blob in one container to another storage account in azure.

I am using @azure/storage-blob 12.0.0 but I cannot figure out how to copy a blob to another container without downloading it.

Maybe someone can help and post a quick example.

Stefan

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written so far.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concern, could you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to copy blob with nodejs sdk `@azure/storage-blob`, you can use the method `BlobClient.beginCopyFromURL` to implement it. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobclient?view=azure-node-latest#begincopyfromurl-string--blobbegincopyfromurloptions-).

For example(copy blob from one container to another container in same storage account)

```
const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

async function copy(){

    const account = "blobstorage0516";
    const accountKey=""
    const cert = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account,accountKey)
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
      `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
      cert
    );
    
    const sourceContainer=blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("test")
    const desContainer=blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("copy")
    //if the desContainer does not exist, please run the following code
    await desContainer.create()
    
    //copy blob
    const sourceBlob=sourceContainer.getBlobClient("emp.txt");
    const desBlob=desContainer.getBlobClient(sourceBlob.name)
    const response =await desBlob.beginCopyFromURL(sourceBlob.url);
    const result = (await response.pollUntilDone())
    console.log(result._response.status)
    console.log(result.copyStatus)
}

copy()
```

[image]

Comment: Anyone know if there is an additional expense copying to a different container over copying to the same container?

Comment: I am copying from archive to cold which can take up to 15 hours. What is the best way to fire this off and forget?

Comment: @GinaMarano Regarding the billing, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob#remarks